# Wordpress the_content() validation error

Tags: wordpress, validation

To display content in wordpess I use `<p><?php the_content();?></p>` , but I get validation error:

```
 Line 94, Column 3: document type does not allow element "p" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag
<p>For companies that are willing to minimize their accounting costs or jus bar…
```

If i change `p` to `span` I get same error , maybe someone know any solution to solve this prolbem with validation error ?

Answer (score 0):

the_content() has already p elements in it, so there is no need to wrap it in p.

I would suggest wrapping it in a div.

Comment: As @Klevis says - the_content(), by default, runs wpautop which places paragraph tags where needed. Unless there's a need to presentationally you could just output `<?php the_content(); />`